# Botón en java que su acción sea "hacer nada"

Tags: java, netbeans, botón, joptionpane

quería saber si existe alguna forma de que al momento de presionar un botón en mi JOptionPane, su acción sea quedarse ahí.
Tengo un Login, en el cual no quiero que abra un el siguiente form si encuentra una actualización del programa.
Gracias

Comment: Si el boton no tiene codigo.. seguro se queda ahi... me estoy perdiendo algo en esta pregunta?

Comment: Si tienes un `if actualizacion = true...{ JPanel.visible... } `, entonces invierte la lógica, `if actualizacion = false { JPanel.visible}`. Como ya te dijeron, si dentro de la validacion no hay nada, pues no hace nada. Lo que pasa con preguntas sin código... que la respuesta es "trivial"